# How do I calculate drive space needed when installing a Linux ISO to a VM?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, iso-image

I inherited a project from someone no longer with the company.  I have a bootable ISO of their development machine.  It's 48 GB.

I want to install that ISO to a VirtualBox VM.  I allocated 100 GB during setup for the VHD.  When I install the ISO though, after some time passes, I get an error which says there's not enough space to continue.

Looking for suggestions regarding the best way to continue.  I'm guessing there's something the way the partitions are set up stating much larger sizes for disk capacity -- but no partition is remotely even close to being full.  That's just a guess though; I could really use some help on this one.  Thanks!

Comment: You cannot easily derive the installed size just by looking at the ISO size. You need to look at its contents – and most importantly the uncompressed size of these contents.

Comment: That seems like a huge VM. I'd just try increasing the VDH size in 100GB increments until it works.

Comment: @miravalls... thanks for the reply.  In asking the question I was hoping someone in the community knew to how do this in a more automated/less manual matter.  I don't believe the VM is "huge".  I believe there's probably a mount point(s) which probably has huge allocation but not all of it is being used.  I don't want to restore empty space.  I was hoping there was a way to overcome that.